# Is consumer key and consumer secret Key dynamic?

Tags: javascript, react-native, twitter

I am trying to connect to twitter using RNTwitterSignIn (react-native). 
But it always gives "internal server error orccured".

Access Token and Access Token Secret are generating, i would like to know, are consumer and consumer secret key dynamic or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  The Consumer Key and Consumer Key Secret are intended to be static.  You can re-generate them through the developer tools if you need new keys (during development or if the keys are compromised), but they are intended to be static.